# neo4j docker image seems to go to sleep

Tags: docker, neo4j, cypher

There seems to be an issue with query performance when using neo4j docker image in combination with graphaware's php client at https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client and I am not even sure if it is normal/intended behaviour.

Setup:

- most recent neo4j docker image
- http api querying neo4j via https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client and using http protocol instead of bolt (the bolt connector proved to be not robust)
- all the calls are POSTs
- everything is on the same machine

The problem is that after not querying the api for 30 minutes, the first query takes really long and runs into the timeout of 5 sec (configured in the graphaware client). It seems that neo4j needs to wake up / warm up. Afterwards, queries are very fast (~100 ms). Now even in production there are not enough calls to have neo4j awake all the time. The queries are in general rather complex.

Is this normal behaviour? If it is, are there common strategies to approach this problem instead of making periodic calls to the api?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is normal for Neo4j. Neo4j caches recently touched nodes/edges to make frequently touched nodes cheaper to query. It purges that cache after a period of time to save on memory.

Here is the Neo4j documentation on how to "warm" the cache to prevent the issue, however if you have a pretty cold server (I.e., infrequent queries) you will need to warm it up before you do an intense query, or you'll always suffer that cold-start cost.

https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/warm-the-cache-to-improve-performance-from-cold-start/

Comment: Thank you very much. According to the article you linked apoc.warmup.run helps, yet we already had it running every 5 minutes without the wanted result. Is there anything else to it?

Comment: How large is your graph, and what do your queries look like? Apoc will attempt to load one page at a time, and it will *not* load properties. So if you're using a lot of properties in your queries, Apoc won't help unless you pass the "loadProperties" array in with the properties you want to load (warning: I've never actually passed properties in, so I'm not sure what that will do to your disk load). You could also create a custom "warmup" query that hits the nodes and properties you care about specifically.

Comment: I reproduced with a very small graph, <10000 nodes. Yes, the queries use a lot of properties, although should be fine with apoc.warmup.run(true)? Can it be an issue that I have ~50 instances of the image running on the machine? Does it force neo to purge the cache faster? Do other things on the machine?

Comment: Ok, so with a graph that size, apoc.warmup.run(true) should grab what you're looking for in only a couple pages. It /could/ be an issue with the number of instances you're running (given running 50 instances probably means each instance has very little memory/page). What may be happening (and we're in speculation land now) is that apoc.warmup.run is overwriting the earlier cache info with info from later pages, causing your query to not be fully indexed. You could try increasing "dbms.memory.pagecache.size" and see if that helps your issue since that would allow more cache.

Comment: In progress of testing. Is there a possibility to definitely say whether the cache is there or not? testing via "wait, then query again" is very flaky